# SSD not found by laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation, hard-drive, ssd

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a new HP Envy6 Sleekbook, 8gb ram, 500gb HDD, 32gb SSD. But the SSD is not found. First, I wanted to install Ubuntu on the SSD but only the SATA drive was found. So I went ahead and installed there. 
Now that Ubuntu is installed, the SSD is still not found. It is as if it does not exist, but I promise you it is. 
Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Does the bios see the ssd?

Comment: Is it a hybrid disk drive ? Means is the SSD built inside the Hard disk ? if yes then apparently you cannot access it from ubuntu. I have a 750 GB Hybrid HDD with 32 GB SSD and I am looking for the same answer from about a month, I have found nothing yet not even a method to access the disk inside linux. You can however see that it exists, just go to `Disks` from dash and in left column it should be listed.

Comment: No the bios does not see it. & no, it is not a hybrid drive. It is a totally seperate drive.

Comment: If the bios does't see it then it is either not connected, or broken.

Comment: According to the only spec sheets I could find for a [Envy 6 sleekbook](http://www.shopping.hp.com/shopping/pdf/b5t12ua.pdf)(PDF), the options are a 320Gb (lower model) or 500Gb (see linked PDF) HDD. Nothing is mentioned of an SSD. Perhaps the HDD has a large cache or similar? You won't, and probably shouldn't, be able to access this as a separate drive. It's designed to cache commonly used data from the spinning drive, to aid with common tasks. I'm usure as to whether this is internal to the drive or if not, whether Ubuntu supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the BIOS cannot see the SSD, as you claim in the comments, then the problem you have is one with your hardware and not with Ubuntu. You will need to identify what the problem is, which could be anything from a loose/damaged connection to a broken SSD, and then take the appropriate action. Perhaps you could try plugging the SSD into the slot you usually use for your HDD; this would allow you to determine if the fault is with the connection or the SSD itself.